# The argument type 'Book' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

Tags: flutter

```
                 actions: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                              _bookCollectionReference.add(Book(
                              userId: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid,
                              title: book.title,,
                              author: book.author,
                              photoUrl: book.photoUrl,
                              publishedDate: book.publishedDate,
                              description: book.description,
                              pageCount: book.pageCount,
                              categories: book.categories,
                            ));
                          },
                          child: Text('Save')),
                    ),
```

///class book

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
return {
'title': title,
'user_id': userId,
'author': author,
'notes': notes,
'photo_url': photoUrl,
'published_date': publishedDate,
'description': description,
'page_count': pageCount,
'categories': categories,
};
}
}

Comment: Can you show the ```_bookCollectionReference``` declaration?

Comment: can i see where the '_bookCollectionReference' is declared

Comment: final _bookCollectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('books');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to convert you Dart Class to Map (json) by calling .toMap()

Try the following code inside your onPressed method:

```
_bookCollectionReference.add(
  Book(
    userId: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid,
    title: book.title,,
    author: book.author,
    photoUrl: book.photoUrl,
    publishedDate: book.publishedDate,
    description: book.description,
    pageCount: book.pageCount,
    categories: book.categories,
  ).toMap(),
);
```